# Write length of 495 byte array to device using web bluetooth api

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I am calling a python api endpoint which sends me the data to be written to the device. The data received is in encrypted format and I am converting the same to byte array using below

```
 let codePoints = [];

 for (let i = 0; i < encData.length; i++) {
   codePoints.push(encData.codePointAt(i));
 }

 const arraybufferdata = Uint8Array.from(codePoints);
```

I am trying to write this byte array using following code:

```
characteristic
.writeValueWithoutResponse(arraybufferdata)
.then(() => {
  console.log("successfully written to the device");
});
```

I am getting the below error:
[image]

I also tried writing by splitting the byte array into chunks as follows:

```
writeOut(data, start) {
 if (start >= data.byteLength) {
   console.log("successfully written to the device");
   return;
 }

this.mychar
  .writeValueWithoutResponse(data.slice(start, start + 256))
  .then(() => {
     this.writeOut(data, start + 256);
   });
}

writeBuffer(data, start) {
   this.writeOut(data, start);
}

this.writeBuffer(arraybufferdata, 0);
```

This is throwing error as well. What could be the issue? The device is not accepting the data to be written either.

UI framework: Angular 7
OS: Windows 10
Browser: Chrome 85

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue:

i was writing to the wrong characteristic! (facepalm)

It's working now!